# Xquery search on multiple keywords

Tags: xml, xquery

I have written a basic XQuery that takes a parameter, performs a "contains" parameter on the data and returns the relevant data set.

```
let $search_term:= request:get-parameter("param1",0)
return 
  <root> { 
    for $node in doc('http://localhost:8080/data/doc.xml')/root/node
      for $value in $node/element/value
        where contains((upper-case($value)), (upper-case($search_term)))
      order by $node/title
      return $node
  } <root>
```

How would I go about extending this to search for multiple parameters. In my Java application, the user enters the search string in an edit box. Therefore the search string may contain many words. Currently, this code only allows for searching on the search string as one entire phrase.

Is it possible to parse all of the words in a "param1" into a string sequence in XQuery and then perform a contains-any-of on this sequence. Finally, in extension, can I then order the results by the number of matches.

Thanks.

Comment: For full text searching you should consider [XQuery and XPath Full Text 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-full-text-10/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a search parser either in java or Xquery to do that.
if it is a Xquery database like MarkLogic or exist-db u could leverge their Search APIs and Index.

if you want a simple search on single node text then you could transform users input into a REGEX and use fn:matches. Beware of XQuery injections in that case though.

looking at your code snippet i would like to suggest one more thing. please consider using Xpath as much as possible rather than for loop which is performance consuming.

Comment: "please consider using Xpath as much as possible rather than for loop which is performance consuming." There may be some XQuery processors where that is true, but I can't imagine it is true in general. Can you cite any evidence for this assertion?

Comment: with my experience XPath parser is more powerful and cacheable internally by an XML/XPATH/XSLT/XQUERY database/engine point of view than user feed XQuery - for loop with predicates and conditions. further if an environment having an powerful XML database having XQuery/xPATH engine then i would say leverage some aspects of database. when we query large mass of Xml clob try go by the order of  Database specific Xml node indexes -> Xpath -> user defined for loop( where/orderby/groupby ) | method branching would give you better results.

Comment: I suspect your experience is with one particular product, and you are making the mistake of assuming it can be extrapolated to other products.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do something like replacing

```
where contains((upper-case($value)), (upper-case($search_term)))
```

by

```
where some $v in tokenize($value, '\s'), $k in tokenize($search_term, '\s')
satisfies upper-case($v) = upper-case($k)
```

However, I fear the results may be disappointing to users accustomed to intelligent free text searching available from engines like Google. Rather than building your own crude free text searching, it would be better to use something that does the job properly.